# JSPM not creating js file in root directory

Tags: jspm, bootstrap-wysiwyg

## Overview

I'm trying to install the *bootstrap-wysiwyg* package in my ES6 project using JSPM.

Usually you can just install a package using the command

> jspm install npm:bootstrap-wysiwyg

And JSPM will take care of the `config.js` file and create the entry JS file in the `jspm_packages` folder.

---

## My problem

For this particular package, it **does** create the `config.js` entry to the bootstrap-wysiwyg JS file in the root directory, but it **does not** create that JS file itself.

---

## Files

**Config.js**

```
"bootstrap-wysiwyg": "npm:bootstrap-wysiwyg@1.0.4",
```

**Import**

```
import stuff from 'bootstrap-wysiwyg';
```

**Error message**

```
GET http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/bootstrap-wysiwyg@1.0.4.js 404 (Not Found)
```

---

## Question

How can I make sure JSPM creates that file? I could make one myself, but then version control is obviously broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module your are trying to import is missing "main" entry in its package.json: https://github.com/steveathon/bootstrap-wysiwyg/blob/master/package.json Therefore, JSPM cannot create the main import. You have to either import files directly from the module (i.e. import stuff from 'bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/smth') or create an override for this package which will define "main" for the package (https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#testing-configuration).